# Contacts are mysteriously disappearing from Moto G (1st gen)

Tags: contacts, 5.0-lollipop, google-account, motorola-moto-g

I have a Motorola Edition G 1st Generation running Android Lollipop 5.0.

I have contacts that have been synced thorough Google Contacts and are cross synchronized through 4 Google Accounts. Some of my contacts, specifically the important ones, have started to disappear for no reason at all.

Comment: Check [contacts.google.com](http://contacts.google.com) to see if your contacts are disappearing from the Google account or the phone itself.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with my Moto G (1st gen.). with just one google account, and FB, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc accounts, all my contacts suddenly disappear and the contact and other apps were really slow.
I resolved my problem completely, the solution was uninstall the Linkedin app, it was artificially multiplying my contacts in other apps and causing slowness and that the contacts did not show in other apps.

Comment: Did you mean "that resolved" instead of "not resolved"?

Comment: Ok, now I solved it !. The guilty app was Linkedin, it was multiplying my contacts, I had to uninstall it, then all the problems with my contacts gone.