# somehow newly saved contacts get disappeared

Tags: contacts, motorola-moto-g3

I'm using MOTO-G Turbo edition. Somehow my newly saved contacts get disappeared. Sometimes it saves and works fine but sometimes it saves and did not show me in my contacts list.

*Can anyone please suggest me what should I do in this case? Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Have you checked with the [other ~40 questions asking the same](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=contacts+disappear+is%3Aquestion) – especially [those ~20 having answers](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=contacts+disappear+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1)? Did they help you? Especially see: [Contacts are mysteriously disappearing from Moto G (1st gen)](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/103842/16575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue with my Moto G (3rd gen) with just one google account.

When new contact adding it will disappear. I resolved my problem by the following solution. The solution was to disable google contact sync. I fixed my problem. But I not sure what is exact cause for this issue. This is a workaround solution.

I hope this is a help if someone doesn't want to sync contact with google.